# Options Menu in MaterialSearchBar with NoActionBar - not showing the icons of overflow menu items and no action by clicking on item?

Tags: java, android, uisearchbar, optionmenu

I hope someone can help me to solve this problem. I have an Activity with MaterialSearchBar and NoActionBar and I want to implement an options menu with items in it. The items should have their icons. So far I wrote the `menu_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_anleitung"
                android:title="Anleitung"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_manual"
                android:orderInCategory="100"
                app:showAsAction="never"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_fb"
                android:title="Feedback"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_email"
                android:orderInCategory="100"
                app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

And added it to the Main.Activity:

1. After my OnCreate-Method I added the following code: `materialSearchBar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);`   and 2. added the following two methods:

   > ```
   > @Override
   >     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   >         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
   >         return true;
   >     }
   >     @Override
   >     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   >         switch (item.getItemId()) {
   >             case R.id.action_anleitung:
   >                 Toast.makeText(this, "Anleitung selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   >                 return true;
   >             case R.id.action_fb:
   >                 Toast.makeText(this, "Feedback selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   >                 return true;
   >             default:
   >                 return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   >         }
   >     }
   > ```

My problem is now the options menu is get showed and by clicking the overflow items get showed but:

1. There are no icons near the item text "Anleitung" and "Feedback". I added already icons-drawables so it's not a problem.
2. By clicking on the items there is no Toast with the text "Anleitung selected" or "Feedback selected".

Did I miss something in the methods or codes? Or is it an issue of MaterialSearchBar which has another methods for options menu. I am trying to solve this problem since days and don't find any solution
Thank you for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write onCreateOptionsMenu or onOptionsItemSelected method.

```
materialSearchBar.getMenu().setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.action_anleitung:
                    //Your Action
                    break;
                case R.id.action_fb:
                    //Your Action
                    break;
                default:
                    return true;
            }
        }
    });
```